# How is a table locked regarding UPDATE-SELECT queries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, update, locking, postgresql-9.3

Is it possible to combine these UPDATE queries?

```
UPDATE myTable1 SET fld1 = myTable2.value
FROM myTable2
WHERE myTable1.id = myTable2.id AND myTable2.style = 45;
UPDATE myTable1 SET fld2 = myTable2.value
FROM myTable2
WHERE myTable1.id = myTable2.id AND myTable2.style = 46;
UPDATE myTable1 SET fld3 = myTable2.value
FROM myTable2
WHERE myTable1.id = myTable2.id AND myTable2.style = 47;
```

And also, how is the lock on these two tables?

Comment: You are essentially asking two different questions, one about combining update statements and the other about locks. That doesn't work well with this site's Q&A format, so please try to avoid that in the future. Other than that, welcome to the site!

Comment: You're right.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question about locks was addressed by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) in the comments to the question:

> an UPDATE will never lock a table - it will only lock the rows that have been updated (in the target table). A select never locks any rows

And as for combining the three update statements into one, yes, it is possible, though not necessarily a good idea. Still, if you insist, here is one way:

```
UPDATE
  myTable1
SET
  fld1 = CASE myTable2.style WHEN 45 THEN myTable2.value ELSE myTable1.fld1 END,
  fld2 = CASE myTable2.style WHEN 46 THEN myTable2.value ELSE myTable1.fld2 END,
  fld3 = CASE myTable2.style WHEN 47 THEN myTable2.value ELSE myTable1.fld3 END
FROM
  myTable2
WHERE
  myTable1.id = myTable2.id
  AND myTable2.style IN (45, 46, 47)
;
```

Basically, you do the join, combine the three filter conditions with an `IN` predicate and in in each of the three assignments you use a `CASE` expression to check if the `myTable2.style` value matches a corresponding value from the filter, so that you can decide whether to assign the `myTable2.value` to the column (`THEN` branch) or keep the old value (`ELSE` branch).

Your three separate statements look clearer/more readable to me, though.

Comment: I would have used `PIVOT` within a `MERGE` statement.

Comment: @MichaelKutz: That's an interesting idea. Of course, this is PostgreSQL 9.3 we are talking about, and so neither `PIVOT` nor `MERGE` is available, but I'd be interested to see what you have in mind. I must add, though, that the way I see it, I doubt very much that using `PIVOT` and `MERGE` would make the logic any clearer, but as an exercise, this would be interesting indeed. And then there's often the performance aspect to take into account, too, so in that regard it's always good to have options. But again, that solution wouldn't work for the OP's database product.

Comment: A google search pulled up the `MERGE` syntax for PostrgreSQL,  I didn't read the fine-print.  "Performance" will probably be RDBMS specific (eg Oracle's `MERGE` would perform significantly better for this case).  As far as "readability" for use of `PIVOT`, that is definitely a concern.  As long as the difference in performance is negligible, I'm not going to argue which method is used (but would probably push for `PIVOT` to changing rows `table2.style in (45,46,47)` into columns `fld1`,`fld2`,`fld3`)